# Correct Observer for after Invoiced issued

Tags: event-observer

I want to run a function AFTER the invoice has been issued.

What is the best event observer? sales_order_invoice_register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sales_order_invoice_save_after` is triggered when the `sales_order_invoice` object is saved.

`sales_order_invoice_register` is an event in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice` method `register`. This method is used to assign data about the invoice to the order.

I would suggest going with `sales_order_invoice_save_after` or, maybe even better: `sales_order_invoice_pay` since that method is called when the invoice is payed.

**Note :** Be careful when using `sales_order_invoice_save_after`. It is triggered everytime, so if the invoice already exists, it is triggered when adding data or whatever. So check carefully that the invoice is in a state you want to have it to run whatever you want to run. You don't know whether the invoice is new. What you can do is adding a flag in the `sales_order_invoice_save_before` event to the invoice object and check for this flag, but `sales_order_invoice_pay` is better. At least if no third party modules didn't use pay() (no example, just my nightmare)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you Rohit. sales_order_invoice_save_after works fine!